# Class member of type Object with http service 'as' syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API that returns:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "name": {
            "title": "mr",
            "first": "konsta",
            "last": "tuomala"
        },
        "email": "kt@test.com"
        ...
```

I'm trying to map a typescript class to this model like so:

```
private name: string;
private email: string;

constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

I can map email as a string but what about name?

Now in my service I do this;

```
return this.http.get('API').toPromise().then(
  response => response.json().results as User[]
)
```

It automatically maps the name object to a User member and I can access it like so in the template:

```
{{user.name.first}}
```

How come there is no error trying to map an object to a string?

What is the right way to handle this kind of data? Do I have to create a Name class and use it as a type for the name member of the User class?

Comment: maybe `Array<User>response.json().results` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript compiler doesn't check your angular 2 template at all, so expression `{{user.name.first}}` just waits to be executed at runtime. If you would put this code directly into your `Component` class code, you would surely be notified.

Type checking is not done in transpiled executed javascript, you receive no error. It's like with typescript interfaces, it just disappears during compilation.

The best what you can do, is to create the type for Name (e.g. `MyName`) with properties `title, first, last` and set it instead of string `private Name: MyName;`

Comment: but in service.user.ts I map the json result to my User class. There must be some kind of implicit conversion from json object to typescript string.

Comment: yes, but again, that's the type check used during transpile (compile) time to javascript. In the javascript runtime, the typechecking is not done again, and result of .json() is exactly the object you have received from your service. Does it makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine.
But your variable `private Name: string` shouldnt be from type string!
It's an object.. so declare it as `any` or as type of `Name` and define that class too.

Remember using cast or `as` will only work with properties but there won't be any functions available from that class..